# Insert points into SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, spatial-query, pymssql

Brand new to python and loving it, and I imagine this might be a simple one.
I am currently inserting points into SQL Server 2008 via a Python script with the help of [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/PymssqlExamples).

```
var1 = "hi"
lat = "55.92"
lon = "-3.29"

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (field1, x, y) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", 
(var1 , lat, lon))
```

This all works fine.
I need to also insert those coordinates into a [GEOGRAPHY type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933834.aspx) field (called geog).

```
geog_type = "geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)',4326))" % (lat, lon)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (field1, x, y, geog) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", 
(var1 , lat, lon, geog_type))
```

This throws the following exception:

> The label geography::STGeomFro in the input well-known text (WKT) is
>   not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT,
>   MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING,
>   COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).

From SSMS I can run an insert statement on  the table to insert a point fine.

```
USE [nosde]
INSERT INTO tweets (geog) 
    VALUES(
        geography::STGeomFromText(
        'POINT(55.9271035250276 -3.29431266523898)',4326))
```

Let me know in the comments if you need more details.

Some of [my workings on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/zSNG9u50)

Comment: Is that the full error message? If so, is geog_type getting truncated in the executed SQL, since the error is complaining about "geography::STGeomFro", rather than "geography::STGeomFromText"

Comment: I stepped through, and the string is correct, so not sure if its getting truncated elsewhere.  http://pastebin.com/D5twLB5h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues - firstly, you're supplying the coordinates in the wrong order - the STPointFromText() method expects longitude first, then latitude.

Secondly, it may be easier to use the Point() method rather than the STPointFromText() method, which doesn't require any string manipulation - just supply the two numeric coordinate parameters directly. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx

But, from the error message, it appears that the value you're sending is attempting to be parsed as a WKT string. If this is the case, you don't want the extra geography::STGeomFromText and the SRID at the end anyway - these are assumed. So try just supplying:

```
geog_type = "'POINT(%s %s)'" % (lon, lat)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (field1, x, y, geog) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", 
(var1 , lat, lon, geog_type))
```

I'm not sure if you need the extra single quotes in the first line or not, but don't have a system to test on at the moment.